# Comparing and deleting records from the same table

Tags: postgresql

I am having a table called communication. This table contains few records with contact_id and few records without contact_id. So,the comm_type and ident columns containing contact_id should be compared with comm_type and ident columns that do not contain contact_id. So, if the not null contact_id's comm_type and ident is matching with null contact_id's comm_type and ident then null's contact comm_type and ident should be eliminated

```
id       contact_id   comm_type    ident  
109901;   114351;         3      "1111111111";
97631;    102177;         2      "Konnection hub#12403";
102924;   109096;         3      "1111111111";
```

```
id        contact_id   comm_type     ident  
109901;                   3        "1111111111";
97631;                    2        "Konnection hub#12403";
102924;                   4        "Aptech interval";
```

In this case first two records which doesn't contain contact_id should be deleted as it's comm_type and ident are matching with records containing contact_id.

I have tried this query, But this isn't getting me the correct output:-

```
BEGIN;
delete from crm.comm_medium m1 where contact_id is not null and  exists
(select 1 from crm.comm_medium m2 where m2.comm_type_id =m1.comm_type_id and m2.ident=m1.ident and contact_id is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested these, and its been a while since I did something like this but see below.

Before doing this substitute the first statement of each with a "SELECT *" to bring back the records which will be deleted, this way you can test your logic before doing irreversible deletion.

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT contact_id
    FROM Table2
    WHERE Table2.contact_id = Table1.contact_id
)
AND Table1.comm_type = Table2.comm_type
AND Table1.ident = Table2.ident
```

or

```
DELETE Table1
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.contact_id != Table2.contact
AND Table1.comm_type = Table2.comm_type
AND Table1.ident = Table2.ident;
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't satisfy the condition....! Because each comm_type and ident without contact_id should be compared with the each comm_type and ident records that contain contact_id.  If same comm_type and ident data are present in records containing contact_id and without contact_id, Only those should be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your original statement was close, just had the NULL conditions reversed:

```
delete from crm.comm_medium m1 
 where m1.contact_id is null 
   and exists
      (select null 
         from crm.comm_medium m2 
        where m2.comm_type_id = m1.comm_type_id 
          and m2.ident = m1.ident 
          and m2.contact_id is not null);
```

Comment: Yup....!!!! It's working and Thank you. Actually i got little confused and have written it reverse.

Comment: But actually i am having a doubt, Does this correlated subquery even work for tables containing more number of columns? Because we will be simply mentioning select 1 or select * , So at times what the outer query takes input to delete?

Comment: Yes, any sub-query  has complete access to the tables it introduces, whether correlated or not. Further a sub-query has complete to the higher query it part of. What makes it correlated is the reference to the higher level. This access does not necessarily pass through a lower sub-query. IE a sub-query of a sub-query may not be able to access columns of the parent (main) query.